# Twitter share button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I want my own image for a Twitter share button and want to also open in a pop-box. It's happening on Facebook, but in Twitter I am able to find out.

Is there a link or solution?

Answer (score 57):

Just point at `https://twitter.com/share?url=<yoururl>` and maybe some other attributes. You don't need the Tweet button code to add a button that tweets.

Comment: Tom, You are right, But which one attribute I need to add

Comment: If I wanted to share a link to google and say "This is awesome!", I'd link to `https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.google.com&text=This is awesome!`

Comment: This is my code "https://twitter.com/share?original_referer=http://localhost:3000/members/the_steal&text=%7BCompliments%20of%20theSTASHBOX.com%7D%20THE%20STEAL:%2030%25%20off%20Original%20String%20Doll%20Gang!%20%7BOSDG%20SECRET%20SALE%20SITE%7D%20http://tinyurl.com/OSDG-TSB%20&url=." But I want to open in pop-up

Comment: Then put it in a `window.open()` or `target="_blank"` code?

Comment: Yes I need window.open(), But where I have to write this.Please give me detail.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had absolutely no idea that we're talking about very low-level javascript (since this is SO I assumed some basic understanding of JS). You can try `<a href="https://twitter.com/share?..." onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Tweet</a>`